# Get element ID from url hash and fire it's click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I would like to grab an element based on the url hash, and fire the click of that element.  I must be missing something, because I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Here's the code

```
jQuery(function($){

    function doUrl() {

        var urlHash = window.location.hash;
        if (urlHash != '') {
            if ( $(urlHash).length > 0 ) {
                $(urlHash).trigger('click');
            }
        }

    }

    doUrl();

});
```

}); // jquery
It seems that the error stems from urlHash not being an appropriate type of element to feed into `$()`.  But the console tells me that the urlHash variable holds what I would expect it to: "#someClickableElement".

When I manually replace the urlHash variable with '#somepageid', the click event still does not fire on page load like I'd expect. So just to clarify, this does not work either:

```
$(function(){
    $('#someClickableElement').click();
});
```

I can't quite tell where my problem is.

---

## Edit

For those of you who want to see the whole code, here's a lot more of it:

```
var map;

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(xxx,xxx),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        }
        // navigationControl: true, // (this is the pan and zoom together)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-area'), mapOptions);


}

// init map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function findMapItem(lat,lon) {

    var buildingLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    map.panTo( buildingLoc );

    removeAllMarkers();

    // add new marker
    buildingMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: buildingLoc,
        clickable: true,
        icon: pathToAssets + 'bobcatMarker2.png'
        //title: ,
    })

    buildingMarkers.push(buildingMarker);


}



jQuery(function($){



    $('.mapItemsControls a').click(function(){

        if ( $(this).hasClass('layerOn') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('layerOn');
        } else {
            $('.mapItemsControls a').not(this).removeClass('layerOn');
            $(this).addClass('layerOn');
        }

        doHistory( $(this).attr('href') );

        return false;

    });


    $('#mapNav .findMapItem').click(function(){

        var lat = $(this).data('lat');
        var lon = $(this).data('lon');
        if (lat != '' && lon != '') {
            findMapItem(lat,lon);
        }

    });


function doUrl() {

    var urlHash = window.location.hash;

    if ( jQuery(urlHash).length > 0 ) {

        jQuery(urlHash).trigger('click');

    }


}

doUrl();

});
```

Comment: Can you post the entire JS code?

Comment: Sounds like it has nothing to do with the urlHash not working.

Comment: We'd need to see all your code, there's nothing wrong with what you've shown so far.  You definitely have errors elsewhere if click() doesn't work, check your console.

Comment: @Leng, console lists no error.

Comment: @Jake Where's the rest of your code? Where is the click handler that you want to trigger?

Comment: @JakeParis, with 4,000+ rep on this site, I'd think you'd know how to post a complete question by now.

Comment: @naomik, with 4000 rep on the site, I also know to _not_ post a wall of code. I think you're right though; the problem is not with the hash.

Comment: Sounds like you just have some code that has an issue with jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Post edited with more code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your click handler declaration comes before the doUrl() function call.

You can also greatly simplify that doUrl() function.

[Click here for a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BdeWZ/3/)

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#test').click(function() {
        alert('No problems.');
    });

    function doUrl() {
        $(window.location.hash).trigger('click');
    }
    doUrl();
});
```

Comment: good thinking on the simplification, but what happens when the element doesn't exist?

Comment: @Jake - jQuery always gracefully fails when the element doesn't exist, that's why you don't need the tests with .length and whatnot.  It performs those tests by default.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting calling the function `doUrl()` inside the Google Maps init block. The functions that the click handler were calling were part of the google maps object and therefore couldn't fire until the Map had been initialized.